Does Screaming Frog support do https securely?
I used Screaming Frog to successfully crawl a site that had an invalid certificate for that domain. I am using Screaming From Version 18.1 on macOS Sonoma 14.5 .
When I tried to open it in Google Chrome, I got a "Privacy Error" (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).
When I tried curl -v in Terminal I got an error (SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name...curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it.
Does Screaming Frog bypass these security checks completely? Or am I missing a configuration setting somewhere?
